# AG-Grid Angular - Select floating filter with ag-grid style

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I already built my CustomFloatingFilterComponent to allow user to select an option from a list to filter values in a column:

[image: Current result]

Here's my code, maybe it can be useful for someone:

**select-floating-filter.component.html**

```html
<span class="ag-floating-filter-input">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange()" class="ag-select ag-select-list">
        <option value="" class="ag-select-list-item"></option>
        <option class="ag-select-list-item" *ngFor="let value of list" [value]="value">{{ value }}</option>
      </select>
</span>
```

**select-floating-filter.component.scss**

```scss
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**select-floating-filter.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IFloatingFilterAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { IFloatingFilterParams, ISimpleFilter } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'owtam-select-floating-filter',
  templateUrl: './select-floating-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-floating-filter.component.scss']
})
export class SelectFloatingFilterComponent implements IFloatingFilterAngularComp {

  private params!: IFloatingFilterParams<ISimpleFilter> & {selectList: string[]};
  selectedValue: any;
  list!: string[];

  agInit(params: IFloatingFilterParams<ISimpleFilter> & {selectList: string[]}): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.list = this.params.selectList;
  }

  onParentModelChanged(parentModel: any) {
    // When the filter is empty we will receive a null value here
    if (!parentModel) {
      this.selectedValue = null;
    } else {
      this.selectedValue = parentModel.filter;
    }
  }

  onValueChange(): void {
    if (!this.selectedValue) {
      // Remove the filter
      this.params.parentFilterInstance((instance) => {
        instance.onFloatingFilterChanged(null, null);
      });
      return;
    }

    this.params.parentFilterInstance((parentInstance) => {
      parentInstance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', this.selectedValue)
    });
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is how to configure the column:

```ts
selectColumn: ColDef = {
    floatingFilterComponent: SelectFloatingFilterComponent;
    floatingFilterComponentParams: {
      suppressFilterButton: true,
      selectList: list
    }
  }
```

I'm just trying to style the dropdown the same as the native ag-grid dropdown, like this:

[image: Expected result]

Is there someway to achive this?
I inspected the page and the native dropdown seems to be a list of divs, without using native select with option, but I can't find anywhere the native "select" component and, personally, I don't want to write from scratch a dropdown component. I know there is built-in SelectCellEditor, but I can't use that for a FloatingFilter.

Thanks in advance!